# If I open this URL in one of the popular browsers, will I probably get a HTTPS error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, headless-browser, ghost.py

I need to write a Python 3 script that answers the question in the title.

By "HTTPS error" I mean both the obvious error page advising user not to proceed and the errors visible in browser console, like “Blocked loading mixed active content”.

So far I tried Ghost.py, but it did not report any errors (with `ignore_ssl_errors=False`) while loading a page that caused “Blocked loading mixed active content”.

Is there a way to fix this in Ghost.py / PySide? Is there another tool I should use?

I would rather not use a tool like Selenium which requires an actual browser, if there is an other way.

Comment: There is a possibility that the page may load insecure content quite sometime _after_ it has loaded (via an extended `timeout` or based on an user action). Hence, it is a rather hard problem to solve, even if you use Selenium/PhantomJS. If you are looking only for the URL's directly mentioned in the HTML page/CSS, then manually verifying that all of them are `https` might be easier.